# How to configure tomcat java for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have maven project. I build it using java 8.

Compilation passed. After it I click `run on server` and select tomcat.

Tomcat uses java 7 to launch builded war and I see error:  unsupportted minor major version.

I cannot find place to configure java version which uses Elclipse tomcat.

Comment: Tomcat uses the `Server runtime`s configured within Eclipse. You must edit that runtime to specify the jdk version (which in turn requires you to configure the `installed JREs` (I can't recall the exact place where these are defined).

Comment: windows -> preferences -> server -> Runtime Environments -> select tomcat 7 -> click edit and determine jre

Comment: @watery please provide answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat uses the `Server runtime`s configured within Eclipse. You must edit the one set in your Tomcat server instance to specify the jdk version (which in turn requires you to configure the installed JREs).

You can find the related settings under Windows → Preferences → Server → Runtime Environments → *select tomcat 7* → *click edit and determine jre*.